# search in data grid view by text box, C#

Tags: c#

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("START_DATE LIKE '%{0}%'", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```

it's return error: 'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.', pls help.

Comment: do a google search on how to search a DataView

Comment: You need to give more information: what is the error, some examples of data in the data source.

Comment: error: 'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.'

Comment: If is easier to query the DataTable source then to query the DGV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("START_DATE = '{0}'", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Or Column name in place of "START_DATE"

```
string rowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] = '{1}'", columnName, filterValue);
(myDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

Comment: thnx very much!